# Is there a simple way to pass a mutable reference into a function value `Fn(T)`?

Tags: rust

I have a function `init` that takes a `configure` lambda in its parameters:

```
fn init<T>(configure: T)
where
    T: Fn<Rc<RefCell<SomeStruct>>>,
{
    let mut some_struct: SomeStruct = /*...*/;
    configure(&mut some_struct); // what to do here?
}
```

How do I create such a thing?

Comment: It is worth clarifying whether you're in control of the `init` function, or `T` is constrained to that trait bound and cannot be changed.

Comment: If this is an accurate representation of the `init` function, its trait bound should be `FnOnce`. Because all `Fn` or `FnMut` closures implement `FnOnce` (but not the other way around), `FnOnce` is the most relaxed requirement that works for `T`. (If you have to call `configure` more than once inside `init`, it should be `FnMut` or `Fn`, in decreasing order of generality.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear what your exact question is, but I guess you should
have tried the most obvious way:

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct SomeStruct;

fn init<T>(configure: T)
where
    T: Fn(&mut SomeStruct),
{
    let mut some_struct = SomeStruct::default();
    configure(&mut some_struct);
}
```